# Audio file always show 0 second length while create using fs node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am trying to create **audio** **file** using **fs** in **node js**.

Here is my code :

```
fs.appendFile(filePath, blob, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            some operation
        }
        return success
    });
```

Now when i open audio file. It open properly and complete audio is here, that i write. But it showing **0 second** of duration.

Comment: There must be more code than that involved?

Comment: There is no more code. I accept blob and filePath as request param. Is anything that i miss?

Comment: Try to use `fs.writeFile` instead, maybe that works. If not, then please also post the code that receives the request.